# Custom UISlider

Tags: swift, slider, customview

Создаю кастомный слайдер для плеера. Назначил картинку для тумблера, но из за того, что он узкий, нельзя докрутить его до конца. Как убрать это ограничение?

[image]

Comment: убедитесь, что изображение обрезано так, как вам надо и нет прозрачных блоков. Другими словами, оно 3х10 а не 10х10

Comment: Спасибо большое - не догадался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

убедитесь, что изображение обрезано так, как вам надо и нет прозрачных блоков. Другими словами, оно 3х10 а не 10х10